# Run Javascript After Page Load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables, startupscript

I understand there are MANY posts on this, but I have tried every single one and none of them work!

I have an aspx and aspx.cs page being run using visual studio 2010.

on my aspx page I have a table

```
<table id="viewPendingTable" runat="server"></table>
```

On the aspx.cs page, the table is loaded with data. This works fine, No Problem. Once the page is loaded, the table contains the dynamically added data I require.

I am using jquery dataTables to style my table using the standard

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#viewPendingTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
    });
});
```

When I create a test table with dummy information directly into the html, the data table displays correctly as required. But when I apply The jquery script to the dynamic table. Nothing happens. The dynamic data is displayed as required, but the data table (search functions, style etc) are not present.

Now I suspect this is because the scripts are run before the table is populated with data.

This is where I began my mission to force the jquery/javascript to run AFTER the aspx.cs has run and the table has been populated.

But I failed... So just as a test I thought I'd run an alert('YAAY'); from the c# side using registered start up scripts. but to no Avail that wouldnt work.

So can somebody PLEASE tell me why this isn't working.

I've tried Multiple Different ways of startup scripts!

My aspx is:

```
<table id="viewPendingTable" runat="server"></table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" id="ShowTable">
<!--
    loadTable();
    function loadTable() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#viewPendingTable').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            });
        });
        alert('ALEX');
        document.getElementById("table_id").width = "100%";
    }
//-->
</script>
```

And my aspx.cs is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadMyTable();
    ClientScriptManager a = null;
    a.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "anotherkey", "alert('ASDFASDFASDF');", true);
    a.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "anfgsdgsderkey", "alert('MOTHER');", false);
    a.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AKey", "loadTable();", true);

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyScript", "<script language=javascript>" + "alert('Hello ASP.NET'); }</script>");

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "script", "alert('Success!');", true);

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "script", "alert('AAA');", true);

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script",
        "alert('a');" +
        "$(document).ready(function (){" +
            "$('#viewPendingTable').dataTable({" +
                "\"bJQueryUI\": true" +
                "\"sPaginationType\": \"full_numbers\"" +
            "});" +
        "}); alert('b'); document.getElementById('viewPendingTable').width = 100%", true);

}
```

I have tried more methods for trying to run javascript after page load but they were lost in the anger of failing so badly.

Somebody PLEASE HELP!

Why aren't my simple javascript alerts running?

Even if I got them to work... would the data table be correctly styled by executing the jquery after page Load???

Thankyou Kindly for your time

Alex

p.s. No comments on asp:gridView or asp:DataTable as That Failed EPICALLY and i posted a question on it days ago and nobody has replied. If you care to take a look 
[CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705454/grid-view-error-visual-studio-2010-asp-net-framework-4-unable-to-find-net-frame)

Comment: What code fills the table? Is there a client side script that does that?

Comment: this is not to the way to use DataTables.net in .NET

Comment: the code that fills the table is purely a sql query that pulls the information, and then adds its using HtmlTableRow.innerHTML and HtmlTableCell.innerHTML

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line of code and try

```
"$('# " +   viewPendingTable.ClientID + "').dataTable({" +
```

in you document.read script that you have written

Its because you can get acutal ID of the table control when the page get render on the browser

**Edit**
Make use of

`RegisterStartupScript` because it emits your JavaScript at the end of the page just before `</form>` tag (before the `<form>` tag ends).

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I would have never figured that out! hahaa But I still have the problem that the scripts arent running in the first place! :(

Answer (score 2):

The most likely issue you're facing is that `id="viewPendingTable"` doesn't exist on your page.

By adding the `runat="server"` attribute on your table, the ID will be changed so that ASP.NET can bind to it on postback.

You'll need to use the `ClientID` property of the table in your jQuery:

```
viewPendingTable.ClientID
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, client side code is ALWAYS run after the server side code is executed. Although client side code can be run before the html is rendered in your browser. So this has nothing to do with that.

If you check the generated html, you will see that asp.net will generate the id's voor the element to which you apply the runat attribute. To solve this, add a class to the table and change your js selector to $(".classname").

Extra tip: Use a debugger like firebug which allows you to debug your js code, which makes it easy to solve problems like these :)